# highlight an image except for a radius around mouse on hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The effect I want to achieve is an image in a div that has a coloured highlight on top (with some opacity to see through it) and when you hover over that image a certain radius around the mouse will have the highlight removed (think of shining a torch over a greyed out image to reveal a brighter around around the torchlight)

I don't know where to start with this because I wasn't sure about dynamically styling a portion of a div without setting proportional properties in css. I know i can achieve a 'blocky' version of this with on hover and styling sections of a div on hover but that means i would have to constrain the styling to seperate div elements and it would not be 'fluid' so I'm looking for some pointers to a js solution I can write (possibly on mouseover call a function that gets mouse position and gets radius around it but then I wasn't sure how to dynamically style that radial area?)

Are there any functions that allow this type of styling within a dynamic area?

Comment: This question is either too broad and so is not suitable for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Made edits. "Are there any functions that allow for styling within a dynamic area" @Paulie_D

Comment: This is **still** too broad.

Comment: @seanyt123 From what i have understand, you want to show a highlighted radial area under the pointer on hovering some div. but you want that radial area to be dynamic based on the element you are hovering on. 
I mean if the div/image area is large you want that radial area to be a little wider and if that div/image area is small you want it to be a bit smaller?
Am i right?

Comment: Sorry @FahadAli no - dynamic as in the area of the circle should be constant around the mouse - so when the mouse moves the circle moves and so does the styling that comes with it.

Comment: @Paulie_D asking for a function(s) to achieve a specific goal is well within scope of SO

Comment: try looking at this example. https://codepen.io/edupoch/pen/GIhJq its something quite nearer to what you want to achieve.

Comment: **Debugging** a function **you** can't get to work is within the scope of SO. Asking for us to write it for you is not.

Comment: @FahadAli That's brill - using the attributes of the event parameter for mousemove callback function to dynamically set css values is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for - I didn't know you could dynamically add css values like that in JS. perfect

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not asking you to write it for me. Asking about the existence of functions and whether someones invented the wheel before me.. which is what this question is. IS within the scope of SO

Comment: Asking for a pre-written function is an **off-site resource** request and equally off-topic. See .4 at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @seanyt123 glad to know that its somewhat related to your solution :)

Comment: @Paulie_D Rule 4 is specifically about recommendations of tools/resources that attract opinion. I'm looking for any function or set off such that solves my well defined problem along with my approach to the problem thus far - see the latter half of .4
This question has an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you're looking for might be achieved through CSS but using JavaScript mouse events can also help.
Like discussed in the comments section, you can use help of the `mousemove` event to somehow achieve what you desire.

For other users reference, here is the link to the codepen https://codepen.io/edupoch/pen/GIhJq

In the codepen above, instead of the zoomin cursor image, you can use some gif image with the effect you want and apply it using the above code.